# Python Visual Studio extension doesn't show errors

Tags: python, visual-studio, ide, warnings, ptvs

I'm used to use VS to code C++ and Eclipse to code python but lately I have tried VS for both languages.

I found something very difficult to understand that while VS autocompletes it doesn't warn you about errors before runtime.

[image: No warning regarding non existent variables or methods]

There is no warning regarding non existent variables or methods. I can't believe that VS does not warn about this kind of typical coding issues as it does for C++ code (as every IDE does).

What am I missing?

I tested this with VS2013 and VS2015.

I'm expecting something like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can configure pylint to run on your python project in PTVS. Have you checked that intellisense definitions have been generated for your Python installation? It usually regenerates when new packages are installed.

Comment: @denfromufa I haven't been able to make it show errors even after installing a new package. I've asked other Windows users and same thing. Does it show errors to you? thanks

Comment: In my case in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I had to install pylint: `pip3 install pylint`, and select it as my linter: ctrl + shift + p --> `python: select linter` --> `pylint`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the python detailed IntelliSense support in VS2015 you have to install python tools for visual studio which provide the following:

1. CPython, PyPy, IronPython and more
2. Detailed IntelliSense
3. Interactive debugging
4. Integrated with Visual Studio features
5. Free and open-source

And the best thing, it's completely free.

Just download it from here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx

I hope it supports your question.

**Update after comment**:

You just need to refresh the Database. It works for me. Check to make sure the environment options are set (specifically path variable to PYTHONPATH) and the DB is refreshed.

Sometimes Deleting the `__init__.py` file in my source root directory did the trick

Comment: Of course I already did that. I can run scripts from VS, I get the autocomplete and so on but there is no warning regarding non existent variables or methods. Have you tried? Try the exact same code I put in the question

Comment: Python Tools doesnt actually 'provide' CPython, IronPython, PyPy, etc. It gives support to those interpreters if you install them.

Comment: Then Microsoft should update their advertisement since it is misleading if you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with a regular Python installation (2.x or 3.x in 32bit or 64bit) there are limited "warnings" (hovering over an undefined variable gives "unknown type"), but Syntax Highlighting / Intellisense doesn't seem to work.

**Intellisense NOT Working:**

[image]

**Getting Intellisense to Work:**

After some research I tried installing another Python interpreter for Visual Studio to work with. I went with Iron Python because it is "tightly integrated with the .NET Framework".

Download it from here --> http://ironpython.codeplex.com/downloads/get/970325

After installing IronPython open Visual Studio and set it as the "Default Environment for New Projects". You can set it in "Tools" --> "Python Tools" --> "Python Environments" (or by pressing Ctrl + K + `)

Make sure to refresh the database and Syntax Highlighting will start working. It doesn't seem very thorough, but it is there.

See photo below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it shows errors but only once you analize it or execute the code.What I mean are the normal warnings that you get underlining in red the methods or variables you use that does not exist. For example here: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OZBlZj05sBQ/U0_ntFJn8RI/AAAAAAAAqPE/-r0FXRswfZU/s1600/posh1.png

Comment: In your own example bad_variable is not underlined neither blabla. That is what I am refering to in my post. :/

Comment: Did you not see the other things underlined? That unequivocally shows functionality - no matter how limited. It seems pretty clear that VS just does not do more than this with Python.